# Does "I want to bid farewell to you" imply the giving of a farewell party?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Does "I want to bid farewell to you" imply the giving of a farewell party? Or can we say it in another way?

Comment: First need to know the real meaning of farewell,how to arrange the farewell party and it is very important to abid in it.....

Answer (score 4):

No, bidding farewell means saying goodbye, it does not mean giving farewell party. If you want to tell a person that you would like to give him/her a farewell party then i think you should say "I would like to throw a farewell party in your honor" or "We have arranged a farewell party in your honor".

Answer (score 3):

Bidding farewell means literally saying *goodbye*. Throwing a farewell party means gathering friends and giving someone a warm send off.

Comment: *Bidding farewell* does not **literally** mean *saying goodbye*. There are various circumstances where *goodbye* is not interchangeable with *farewell*.

Comment: Therefore, party = 'warm send off'; no party = cold shrug.

Comment: ... and various circumstances where *bid* is not interchangable with *say* :)

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not convey an 'internal meaning of giving a farewell party'.  You could bid farewell merely by waving your hand, for example.